# What's the purposed of <Frame.Content> in a Xamarin Forms application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have some code that looks like this:

```
<Frame CornerRadius="20" >
   <Frame.Content>
      <Grid x:Name="detailRowArea" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
         <xaml:CardWordsFourRowsPlus IsVisible="{Binding FourRowsPlus}" />
         <xaml:CardWordsFourRows IsVisible="{Binding FourRows}" />
         <xaml:CardWordsThreeRows IsVisible="{Binding ThreeRows}" />
         <xaml:CardWordsTwoRows IsVisible="{Binding TwoRows}" />
      </Grid>
   </Frame.Content>
</Frame>
```

I just now noticed that the developer had used Frame.Content

Can anyone tell me why this is used?  The code seems to work without it so I am wondering what advantage it offers.

Answer (score 2):

There really isn't any advantage other than I guess readability, but the Content tags really aren't needed. The Forms control in xaml will assume that any content that appears between the start and end tags is assumed to be assigned to the Content property.

If you want a more detailed explanation you can check out the Content Properties section in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/essential-xaml-syntax).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to not use the `<Frame.Content>` tag that is fine, bear in mind that `Frame` descends from `ContentView` thus you would ideally define the content of this view in the `Content` tag. This is more of a semantic decision as opposed to performative decision.

This being said, you would need to use the content tag if you wanted to implement any kind of `OnPlatform` code in your frame. For example *(hand coded, could be wrong)*

```
<Frame>
    <Frame.CornerRadius>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Single">
            <On Platform="iOS">50</On>
            <On Platform="Android">75</On>
        </OnPlatform>
    </Frame.CornerRadius>
    <Frame.Content>
        <Label Text="Hello World"/>
    </Frame.Content>
</Frame>
```

Comment: Your `CornerRadius` type is incorrect it should be `x:TypeArguments="x:Single"` and the on platform part you can use `<On Platform="iOS" Value="50"/>`. Also, even without explicitly using the content tag, the Frame is still able to determine that the content is still the Label.

Comment: I agree with Nick. Any type of ContentView is able to **remove** the `<Frame.Content>` tag, even if specifying OnPlatform tags. `ContentView`'s use a `[ContentProperty("Content")]` attribute. That makes it possible to remove those tags.